# Regex for following condition

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Create a regular expression for the language consisting of the set of strings over Σ = {0, 1} 
**i.e.** input is a string which contains only 1s or 0s. we have to search in a binary string.

Such that each string in the language is either:

**(a)** has a sequence of 5 consecutive 0s, or

**(b)** has a sequence of an odd number of consecutive 1s followed at some point by a sequence of an even number of consecutive 1s.

Thus 00000, 000000, 11100000, 11111, and 10011 would be in the language, 
but 110000 would not.

Comment: What have you tried already and which problems did you encounter? Looks like a [homework question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Why is `111` accepted? Doesn't match any of the conditions.

Comment: Writing a [regex for it](https://regex101.com/r/SqyERe/1), I realize it **does** fall under b :).

Comment: Thanks @ClasG. Your solution worked. Please upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concatenate 2 regexes:

`0{5}` : matches 5 consecutive 0

and

`^1(?:11)*0*(?:11)*0*$`

Group them:

`0{5}|^1(?:11)*0*(?:11)*0*$`

**Explanation:**

```
^       : start of string
  1     : a 1
  (?:   : start non capture group
    11  : that contains two 1
  )*    : repeated 0 or more times, after that you have an odd number of 1
  0*    : 0 or more 0
  (?:   : start non capture group
    11  : that contains two 1
  )*    : repeated 0 or more times, you then have an even number of 1
  0*    : 0 or more 0
$       : end of string
```

Comment: Thanks @toto, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[01]*0{5,}[01]*|[01]*11$
```

for (a) it should matched , but (b) I'm not very clear, does it mean end with `11`?

Comment: I have got it. https://regex101.com/r/SqyERe/1 Thanks for the help @Kerwin